# Is there a way to keep two videos synchronized in a webpage without plugins?

Tags: video, html

Is there a way to use two HTML5 video tags on a page and keep the videos synchronized? Meaning that if the first video is at 15.2 seconds then the second video is at 15.2 seconds?

I've looked around and found SMIL but it looks like that only works in IE. I also tried to implement something of my own with jQuery and jMediaElement but there appears to be a lot of cases where the videos can get out of sync.

Has this been done before?

Comment: interestingly i saw a demo showing the same video of a cat twice and both were synchronized. it wasn't perfect, but a Macbook isn't the most powerful machine either. can't remember where i saw that, lemme google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It was on http://html5demos.com.

Checkout this [demo](http://html5demos.com/two-videos).. works perfectly (well almost) on Chrome for me.

The source is available on the page.

Comment: I've noticed some issues with it, but it's the best so far so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The demo that was presented on html5demos works but it can easily go out of sync.

Here's an article providing a solution that makes use of requestAnimationFrame (info about it: [Leaner, Meaner, Faster Animations with requestAnimationFrame](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/), [Animating with javascript: from setInterval to requestAnimationFrame](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/)) and it's much better: [HTML5 Video: Synchronizing Playback of Two Videos](http://weblog.bocoup.com/html5-video-synchronizing-playback-of-two-videos/).

Note that the demo provided there (hosted at jsfiddle) has a wrong link on a js source. I updated it on this new page:

http://jsfiddle.net/aqUNf/1/

Bear in mind browser support, this feature is supported by Firefox, Chrome, and from Safari 6 and IE 10 (see [table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) for further details). Otherwise it falls back to setInterval, witch doesn't provide the same performance and battery-saving advantage.

(It uses [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) by the way, which is a really nice project by Mozilla)

And here's the code (directly taken from the demo):

```
var videos = {
    a: Popcorn("#a"),    
    b: Popcorn("#b"), 

},
scrub = $("#scrub"),
loadCount = 0, 
events = "play pause timeupdate seeking".split(/\s+/g);

// iterate both media sources
Popcorn.forEach( videos, function( media, type ) {

    // when each is ready... 
    media.listen( "canplayall", function() {

        // trigger a custom "sync" event
        this.trigger("sync");

        // set the max value of the "scrubber"
        scrub.attr("max", this.duration() );

    // Listen for the custom sync event...    
    }).listen( "sync", function() {

        // Once both items are loaded, sync events
        if ( ++loadCount == 2 ) {

            // Iterate all events and trigger them on the video B
            // whenever they occur on the video A
            events.forEach(function( event ) {

                videos.a.listen( event, function() {

                    // Avoid overkill events, trigger timeupdate manually
                    if ( event === "timeupdate" ) {

                        if ( !this.media.paused ) {
                            return;
                        } 
                        videos.b.trigger( "timeupdate" );

                        // update scrubber
                        scrub.val( this.currentTime() );

                        return;
                    }

                    if ( event === "seeking" ) {
                        videos.b.currentTime( this.currentTime() );
                    }

                    if ( event === "play" || event === "pause" ) {
                        videos.b[ event ]();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});

scrub.bind("change", function() {
    var val = this.value;
    videos.a.currentTime( val );
    videos.b.currentTime( val );
});

// With requestAnimationFrame, we can ensure that as 
// frequently as the browser would allow, 
// the video is resync'ed.
function sync() {
    videos.b.currentTime( 
        videos.a.currentTime()        
    );
    requestAnimFrame( sync );
}

sync();
```

Comment: Could you provide me the code to synch both from videos?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to play video at all without plugins is with HTML5 or SVG <video>. There is no reliable method of keeping two HTML5 videos synchronized, but if exact sync isn't critical you could probably get pretty close by just calling play() at the same time or otherwise calling play() and pause() on the two videos to get them in approximate sync as hinted at by Simeon.

As for SVG <video>, SVG already has some small (and modified) subset of SMIL, so it may already be supported in the spec, but to my knowledge no browser will handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like even Opera has this issue (10 MAR, 2010) :

> **There's currently no good API for synchronizing things with the timeline of a video**, for instance captions or infoboxes. The spec has had "cue ranges" for this purpose earlier (which even earlier were "cue points"); it is expected that something similar will be added in the future

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/

Btw, the article is really interesting, and maybe you will find some useful tips in it.

Comment: Cue ranges have been taken out of the HTML5 spec. The track element accomplishes something similar: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#the-track-element; http://blog.gingertech.net/2010/08/07/websrt-and-html5-media-accessibility/

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the challenge of synchronizing multiple videos and found the process to be very complicated. As a result, I created a package called sync-video-player that can synchronize two or more videos.

It's true that this is a plugin, but it's worth taking a look at the source code as well.

If you're interested in the implementation, feel free to take a look at the code on GitHub:

[sync-video-player](https://github.com/pataiadam/sync-video-player)

It's worth noting that this package is relatively new, but I use it actively in my own projects and am committed to maintaining it. If you encounter any issues, please don't hesitate to report them.