# How to keep synchronized video element especially after pause/play event in (html5/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I try to have in a html5 webpage project three  elements fully synchronized. To ensure no shift due to video download, I put the attribute preload="auto" to the video elements.

My script is as follows:

```
    var run = document.getElementById("run"); //run is a button element
    var vid = document.getElementById("video1"); // the first video element

    function PlayVideo() {
        if (vid.paused) {
            vid.play();
            run.textContent = "||";
        } else {
            vid.pause();
            run.textContent = ">";
        }       
    } // The PlayVideo() function is called onclick on the run button

    $('#video1').on('play', ambiance = function(){
    document.getElementById("video2").play();
    document.getElementById("video3").play();       
    });

    $('#video1').on('pause', ambiance = function(){
    document.getElementById("video2").pause();
    document.getElementById("video3").pause();      
    });
```

When using this piece of script after waiting few seconds to a complete load of the video files, the run button plays correctly the first video and the two others start synchronized. But when I pause the run button pushing a second time on it, only the first video stops and the two others continue to be played during 2 or 3 seconds (both of them synchronized but not with the first one).

Could you help me?
Is there an other way (more elegant) to play synchronized video?

One last element: the source of the three video is the same. (Same video played in each elements).

Thank you

Comment: already exists a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654817/is-there-a-way-to-keep-two-videos-synchronized-in-a-webpage-without-plugins

Comment: I tried the linked code and it is not synchronized at all! The two videos are running to be in phase, being not all the time unsynchronized. (on Chrome at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

function playAll() {
  [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
     video.play()
  });
}

function pauseAll() {
  [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
     video.pause()
  });
}

// this keeps everything synchronized
[].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
  video.addEventListener('play', playAll, false);
  video.addEventListener('pause', pauseAll, false);
});
```

Keep in mind there will probably still be a slight offset (if you have sound it'll sound distorted)

Comment: Thanks a lot.The last function seems to slow down the video streams (on my computer at least, using Chrome V39.0. I removed this part of the function, and I put in the pauseAll() function some instructions to take the currentTime of one of the video and set it to the other. This way, each time the video is paused, it will be resynchronized at play.

Comment: whoops, I left both listeners as "play" by accident. the second should be pause, obviously.